# mysqldump: Got error: 1054

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer um Dump para fazer um Junção de Banco de dados. Segue comando:

```
mysqldump -u root -p senha -hlocalhost --opt -t --where codemp=1 database > emp01.sql
```

O mesmo está retornando o erro

> mysqldump: Got error: 1054: Unknown column 'codemp' in 'where clause'
>   when retrieving data from server

Esta coluna existe. Alguém já viu ou pegou algum caso assim?

Captura de Tela

[image: Captura de Tela]

Comment: Mostre um print dessa tabela por favor

Comment: faz um select nessa tabela e mostra o print

Comment: tente o nome da tabela + campo, `where minhatabela.codemp=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o problema seja que vc não especificou a tabela no comando.

```
mysqldump -u root -p senha -hlocalhost --opt -t [NOME_DA_TABELA] --where codemp=1 database > emp01.sql
```

Comment: São mais de 700 tabelas, terei que fazer para todas então?

Comment: Deu certo. Muito Obrigado.